# Creating Reports in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I need to develop a report. I have no idea about reporting services or crystal reports so I will begin learning stuff from scratch. However I need guidance from you all.
I want to convert this Excel sheet into a Report. 
[image]
Some friends suggested it is a Matrix Report and will be  developed using SSRS. But I need advice from stack overflow's experts. Also please provide some links to study building such reports as I am totally new.

Comment: You can use...crystal to develop the report you have pasted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friends are absolutely right - Matrix Report in SSRS will do exactly that
For your convenience, I’m including a few links ON SSRS to help you get started

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsZCzeRKYcs - very good overview
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-basics-building-ssrs-reports/ - basics
```

and [Tutorial: Creating a Basic Matrix Report](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627441(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity; can I achieve the same results from crystal? Like can we make matrix Reports using crystal Reports?

Comment: Yes, same can be done with Crystal as well, but from my experience, after Crystal was bought by SAP they are getting buggy and poorly supported, while MS quality and features are on the rise.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [DoddleReport](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/) but that depends on your requirement as  you can't do much customization in DoddleReports,

http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/